# `Angularjs` call to `WebMethod` with `PARAMETERS`

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angularjs, webmethod

How to post parameters  to `[WebMethod]` using `angularjs`.

My angularjs script is::

```
app.factory('checkAvabService', function ($http) {
    return {
        checkFare: function () {
            return $http.post('onewaydomflt.aspx/checkAvab', { 

             data:{test:"hello"} //post test as parameter to web method

          })
        }
    };
});
```

My Web Method is::

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string checkAvab(string test)  // string test is not accept value "hello"
{
    string x = test;
    return x;
}
```

Here I am not getting **test** parameter value **hello** to `WebMethod`.

Whats wrong in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass data in the 2nd parameter of `$http.post` call which takes data in JSON format. There is no need to use `data` again in object which you are passing.

```
return $http.post('onewaydomflt.aspx/checkAvab', {test:"hello"})
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Pankaj Parker. Now webmethod accept parameter fine ... thanks again

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks man for heads up.. but may I know while posting any data to ASP.Net MVC -4 action, why we need to pass request body in stringified format. Just asking for curiosity..

Comment: I don't know anything about ASP.Net MVC -4, and am not sure what you mean by "stringified format".

Comment: @JBNizet I meant to say, before sending data to server I stringify it(`JSON.strigify(data)`)..

Comment: I don't see why this would be of any use. Angular transforms the objects passed to $http to JSON by default: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations *If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.*

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much for the information.. I think the older version of specially (1.2.19) doesn't have this serialization thing(I'm using older version in my project).. thanks again..

Comment: It has that since the very beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108016/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-jb-nizet).